# How do I change font of "String to Curves" Geometry node using Blender python?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, text-object

I want to make it easier for people to change fonts without going into the geometry nodes editor.

But I don't know how to select the "String to Curves" node.

Hovering mouse over the node shows me how to change alignment.

```
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].nodes["String to Curves"].align_x = 'CENTER'
```

[image]

But if I hover over the font section of the node, it shows this python code, which doesn't work

```
VectorFont.name
bpy.data.fonts["Bfont Regular"].name
```

There is code online to load a data font

```
data_font = bpy.data.fonts.load('C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Font.ttf')
```

But I don't know how to select a specific geometry node and apply the font to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few bits to this:

- Select the object that has the Geometry Node modifier.  I'll use the active object in my example.  If you don't want to use the active object you'll have to change the first line.
- Select the Geometry Node modifier on that object. I'll search by name, but if you've changed the name of your modifier you'll need to use your name in your code.  It's actually better to search by type if you have multiple modifiers.
- Select the node group from the modifier.
- Select the *String to Curve* node from the node group.  I'll search by name, but see above.
- Finally, set the `font` member of the node.  You can learn what member by looking in the manual for [`bpy.types.GeometryNodeStringToCurves`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GeometryNodeStringToCurves.html#bpy.types.GeometryNodeStringToCurves.font)

Here's the code, without any error handling.  You should check to see that there is an active object, that it has a modifier, and that there is, in fact, a *String to Curves* modifier if you want more robust code..

```py
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
node_group = modifier.node_group
node = node_group.nodes['String to Curves']
data_font = bpy.data.fonts.load('C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Font.ttf')
node.font = data_font
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.